# Installing Matplotlib with PIP

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

When I try to run my python script I get the following error

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

SO I tried to install Matplotlib using 
    "pip install matplotlib"

Then I get the error

```
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: functools32 in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-
packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=1.5.6 in 
c:\users\harla\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib)
```

I know I have installed anaconda. I don't want to use Anaconda for this. How do I install  the library matplotlib ?

Comment: Did you `activate` your environment?

Comment: seems like you have using windows then check with wheel installation for python windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the environment variable to C:\Users\harla\Anaconda2\Scripts_flag

Not sure if there is a better solution.